# What's the approach for handling transactions in java across multiple data stores?

Tags: java, sql, transactions, nosql

I would like to know what's the best way to handle transactions across multiple data stores involving database and file system?

Here is the scenario:

Consider I have a a system wherein I have to store data, which contains text and binary. The text provides metadata information and binary data is the actual data to be stored. Also data should be searchable based on the metadata set by the client.

This brings the architecture to store the data in 3 forms
1. Store the binary data on to a file system
2. A record in RDBMS containing pointers(id, location) to the binary data on the file system
3. A record in a indexing engine like Solr/Lucene for search requirements based on metedata.

Please note that usage of RDBMS is for reliability so that re-indexing can be done in case the Solr/Lucene index is corrupt.

The challenge in the above scenario is that each one of them are different data store and have their own transactional behavior. The RDBMS provides me the transaction capability however the other two does not.

Now the question is that, I want to create a transactional behavior across multiple data stores. This means that failure in any of the data store should revert back the changes on the other two.

It also puts a question on which should be the primary data store from where the information has to be searched and hence the order of data storage into each of the data stores would become very important.

In an example I would like to do the following

1. Write the file onto file system
2. Create the Index on Solr/Lucene
3. Insert the record into the database.

In the above case if the database insert fails and retry happens, then we can overwrite the data onto file system as well as the index engine. Because you do not want a situation that you have a database record and no data stored in the file system in case  of a server crash.

Now if the search is primarily served by the search engine then it can have stale data for which no corresponding record exists in the database. This means that there is an consistency issue across data stores.

I believe that one requires some kind of state engine, which understands the state of each record across data stores till the last commit and has the ability to clean up stale data.

I would like to know are there any other approaches to handling this? What are the other techniques to handle such a situation for inserts and updates of data across multiple data stores?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously your question describes a pretty complex scenario. Writing data across multiple data stores and wanting the writes to be transactional across all systems.

I can think of three ways of doing this.

**Use a Service Bus**

Mule ESB (http://www.mulesoft.org/) provides its own transaction functionality and will let you write data to multiple systems fairly easily.

The difficult part would be implementing a rollback strategy in case of one of the writes failing. But Mule was definitely my first thought because it has good integrations with lots of systems and it supports the idea of transactions.

**Mark Records as Dirty**

The second approach is to introduce a dirty flag to every record in each system. As you begin a transaction, you write the data and have a "dirty" flag set to 1 for each record in each system.

If all writes succeed, then you need to go back and set the flag to 0. If it fails, it's fairly easy to go back and delete anything that is dirty.

For reads, you will never read anything that is dirty.

If you were writing four pieces of data, you could write three, the fourth fails and instead of re-doing the entire transaction, you could just keep retrying the fourth until it succeeded. Then go back and mark everything as dirty=0.

**Java JTA**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API.  If you can wrap everything in X/Open XA architecture, then this might work.